# Create PDF via custom HTML Document

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to generate an HTML document which I then want to use to create a PDF.
I want to use 2 templates A4.html and td.html which roughly look like so:

A4.html

```
!<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title Goes Here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
{PLACEHOLDER}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

td.html

```
<td>
{PLACEHOLDER_VALUE}
</td>
```

First I build the content with td.html replacing the value placeholder with values from a list and then inserting the resulting HTML code into the first template, sounds simple enough but I cant seem to find anything that loads from a file and then support placeholder insertion. Any suggestions on how to implement this are welcome (please note the template examples here are very simplified)

Comment: look up `ITextSharp` it's free ...and it's so easy

Comment: Your post is tagged `C#` but you are using `.html` files? Are you sure this is related to C#?

Comment: ITextSharp license requires me to make the source public, witch is a no go

Comment: Yes, its a ASP.NET C# Forms application witch generated PDFs via HTML